# Google search for searching sites supporting HTTPS

Tags: google-search

What do i have to type in a google search that only gives hits (domains) supporting HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets me close ...

[inurl:https -inurl:http](http://www.google.nl/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sd#sclient=psy&hl=nl&source=hp&q=inurl:https+-inurl%3Ahttp&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=b623321168b61895)

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer for google, but if you are looking to have way more information on webservers, I highly recommend going to [www.shodanhq.com](http://www.shodanhq.com/), follow the how-to's and you will find incredible information on millions of webservers running ssl and much much more...

Be responsable, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you use firefox browser install this addon on firefox
https://www.eff.org/files/https-everywhere-latest.xpi
this addon will enable https protocol on any site that support this protocol.